# how to write file with buffer array using put method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

Is there any way to write file using buffer array and content-type with put method?

```
requestify.request('some url', {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: buffArray, //need modifications here
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': res_file.headers['content-type']
                    }
                }).then(function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                })
```

I could send the data but file not storing in proper way.

working Java code

```
   httpcon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        httpcon.setReadTimeout(100000);
        httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", conenttype);
        httpcon.connect();
        OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();

        os.write(in.toByteArray(), 0, in.size());

        responceCode = httpcon.getResponseCode();

        httpcon.disconnect();
```

Comment: How does your server handle the request?

Answer (score 1):

My personal advice here is to use the builtin `http` or `https` package from Node.JS.

Why? Because you want to write and read binary files that might be large enough to give you problems, and as for what I've tested with `requestify`, it will give you problems when using binary responses (It stringifies them!).

You can simply use streams which will save you lots of headaches.

You can test it using this, for example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('https');

const req = http.request({
  host: 'raw.githubusercontent.com',
  path: '/smooth-code/svgr/master/resources/svgr-logo.png',
  method: 'GET'
}, res => {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.png'));
});
req.end();
```

and adapted to your provided code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('https');

const req = http.request({
  host: 'some-host',
  path: '/some/path',
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': res_file.headers['content-type']
  }
}, res => {
  res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('your-output-file.blob'));
});
// This part: If comes from HDD or from another request, I would recommend using .pipe also
req.write(buffArray);
req.end();
```

Further info:

http package https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

fs package https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html